# How to Generate border utilities classes using scss

Tags: html, css, sass

Hello guys I want to create a list of classes for border-width proprety using scss
take a look to this example https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWuj5.png

How can I do this using **SCSS**

```
$line-widths: (
    "line-y-0": 0, // border-top-width: 0;
    "line-x-0": 0, // border-left-width: 0;
    "line-y-2": 2px, // border-top-width: 2px;
    "line-x-2": 2px, // border-left-width: 2px;
    "line-y": 1px, // border-left-width: 1px;
    "line-x": 1px, // border-left-width: 1px;
    "line-y-reverse": 1, // --line-y-reverse: 1;
    "line-x-reverse": 1, // --line-x-reverse: 1;
) !default;
```

Answer (score 1):

YOu can do something like this:
It will help you to set any direction's border.

```
 @mixin border($direction, $width) {
  border-#{$direction}-width: $width;
 }

.atul{
  @include border(left,2px);
}
```

just created an example for you, where you can play with this.
https://gist.github.com/atulkumargrazitti/ce692d1d97f05d76c36449fa6e25797a

Comment: I want ot use classes in html example : line-y-2 border-left-width: 2px;

Comment: thank you guys for your help but I want the same idea like this https://i.imgur.com/0E3x1nG.png use utilities classes using SCSS

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can try something like this.

```
$line-widths: (
    0,
    1,
    2,
    4,
    8
);

@each $width in $line-widths {
    .line-x-#{$width} {
        border-left-width: $width;
    }

    .line-y-#{$width} {
        border-top-width: $width;
    }
}
```